# One product ( server side / client side 1 / client side 2... ) in one repository git

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have problem connected with structure of git repository. I was working for a while with SVN, so maybe this change my mindset a little bit. Our team developing one product, let's name it "deep". 
"deep" has:

- server side (php/db)
- android app
- windows phone app
- ios app

I'm android app developer so I don't need ios,windows phone and server side code. My friend don't need my code. Is there any chance to work only with part of the master which I need and don't interact with other parts at all.

Why we want to have it in one repository is the fact, that these all parts should be on the same stage of development, when we make a release. To make it more visible, there is a point in time when we want to make release, so Android app should support the same amount of functionalities as server side, windows phone, ios.

And what's more in my opinion it looks cleaner to have one repo = one product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for submodules, you each have your own repository, but you stage certain commits in your main repository of all the different modules. That way everyone can work with a stable copy of each others work, but still work on their code with out affecting others.

Comment: Thx for answer, we tested this approach and it's seems to be great solution for our problem :)